# Is App Bundle enough or the APK Splits necessary to reduce an APK size?

Tags: apk, android, android-app-bundle, opencv

I'm using **OpenCV** Library v4.1.2 to implement the GrabCut algorithm, I use only the following :

```
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
```

After generating the APK, it's come with huge size **70MB**

**Gradle:**

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "abc.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

**My Question:**

Is Android App Bundle enough to reduce the APK size or I should split it by each architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When publishing an Android App Bundle, Play will do the split by ABI (and DPI and language) for you. This is one of the major benefits of the Android App Bundle: you only have to publish a single artifact with a single versionCode and Play can manage all the best practices around reducing the size of your app on your behalf.

Comment: thank you, now I got it, I thought although I use the abb it's necessary to split the APK

Answer (score 2):

Although, you are allowed to upload apps with size under 100MB to Google Play Store, it is highly recommended that you use Android Abb Bundle feature. It's very easy to implement:

```
bundle {
   language {
       enableSplit = true
   }
   density {
       enableSplit = true
   }
   abi {
       enableSplit = true
   }
}
```

As you are supporting four abis: `'armeabi-v7a'`, `'arm64-v8a'`, `'x86'` and `'x86_64'`, using Android Abb Bundle will reduce the dize of the final package downloaded by user from Google Play Store significantly. From the information you gave, I guess it will be lowered by half to about 30-40MB.

If you don't have your app localized into other languages or if the localization files do not take up much space you can set `language {enableSplit = false}`, same logic goes for the density, if you don't have much space taken up by different density dependent files.

Comment: Note that the values for `enableSplit` are `true` by default, so the whole `bundle {}` block can be omitted if you're happy with these values.

Comment: @sergei what happen if you set density enable split to true and the user on his tablet do a resize  of the app ? The app will crash beacause there aren 't all dp resources ?